# AngularFire2 RealTime Database returned data doesnt look like the data in firebase

Tags: angular, angularfire2

## My Data

[image]

## My Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.current = db.list(`products/${this.product['sku']}/data/config`).valueChanges();
}
```

## My Template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="current">
    <div *ngFor="let set of current|async">
        <!-- this level works as expected -->
        <div *ngFor="let option of set.options">
            <!-- console reads: find a differ supporting object. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables -->
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

## Problem

Looks like the problem I need help with is `set.option` is an object of objects. So I tried to do `*ngFor="let option of toArray(set.options)">` which works but when i console.log something in `toArray()` it keeps printing stuff to the log. Is that bad?

## question

How should I make `options` in to an iterable array

Answer (score 0):

With AngularFire v5 we went with a more NGRX-friendly API. You data will be in the `.payload` part of the `Action` interface.

For your case you though, probably want an object (since you don't want to observe each key separately) and since you already know the key (and presumably not using NGRX), you could use the more simple API `.valueChanges()`:

```
setCurrent(product_id) {
    return this.db.object(`products/${product_id}`).valueChanges();
}
```

I'd suggest reading up on our docs some more https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#realtime-database

Comment: thank you for this answer. Im sorry i dont think i explained my problem well. I modified the question with your thoughts in mind. Do you mind taking a look now?